# Get address of __regvar variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, cpu-registers, iar

At the moment I'm working in a poject for an embedded system in which we're using a AVR ATMega8 microproccessor. As it has a quite small memmory area, I'm trying to store some global variables into registers using the __regvar command.

I need to access those variables from multiple files so instead of making all of them external I had thought about making external only a pointer to the first one and through offsets modify all the variables.

For example:

Global 1  --> $Reg4
Global 2  --> $Reg5
Global 3  --> $Reg6
Global 4  --> $Reg7

Pointer = AddressOfGlobal1

And with that I can modify all registers just by adding 1 (1 byte)

The problem is that I can't get the address of that variable:

```
__no_init __regvar unsigned char ms_flags@ 4; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char tb_flags@ 5; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char st_flags@ 6; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char dp_flags@ 7; 


int myfunction(){


 unsigned char* pointer     = 0;

    pointer = &ms_flags;
}
```

Getting the following output:

Error[Pe513]: a value of type "unsigned char __regvar *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "unsigned char *" C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\app\init.c 39

Comment: I don't know this compiler very well but... if the variable is always stored in a register, how can it have an address?

Comment: Oh...very stupid question. Sorry, i'm a bit confused

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that; a value stored in a register *has no address*, by definition. That's the point, the thing that you're jumping through hoops to achieve.

The draft C99 standard says, in §6.5.3.2:

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result 
>   of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a 
>   bit-field and is not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.

If we peel off the compiler-specifics, I'm pretty sure `__regvar` somehow implies `register`.

Comment: Yes, that's completely true.